# 1-forms vs k-forms vs Vector Fields

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms, vector-fields, tangent-spaces, co-tangent-space

I'm trying to get a comprehensive understanding of similarities and differences of differential forms and vector fields. As I understand, 1-forms are analogous to vector fields in that for a vector field $X \in \Gamma (TM)$ and a 1-form $\xi \in \Gamma (T^*M)$ defined on an n-dimensional manifold $M$ we have

$X: M \rightarrow TM$

$\xi: M \rightarrow T^{*}M$

where $X$, $\xi$ are sections of $TM$ and $T^{*}M$ (resp.), and $X(p)$, $\xi (p)$ are tangent vectors and cotangent vectors (resp) for any $p \in M$.

With this correspondence of 1-forms and vector fields, I'm wondering if there is an equivalent object from the world of vector fields which corresponds to $k$-forms for $k>1$. For a $k$-form $\omega$ defined over $M$ we have

$\omega: M \rightarrow \Lambda^{k}T^{*}M$.

This $k$-form is created by some operation on 1-forms (wedge product), is there an analogous operation defined on vector fields to create some "$k$-vector field"?

I find that in differential geometry there are so many different objects living in different spaces, I am trying to simplify and draw similarities where possible. This is what motivates the above question.

Comment: Exactly analogously to $k$-forms, you can define the so-called multivector fields as sections of $\Lambda^k TM\to M$. An example of where they might come up: a Poisson structure on a manifold is a bivector field ($k=2$) satisfying an integrability condition (having to do with the extension of the Lie bracket to multivector fields called the Schouten bracket).

Comment: The operations on the 1-forms to get k-forms can be fine to every vector space, look here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_algebra. If you do this to every fibre of a vector bundle, you get a new bundle. If you do this to the tangenti bundle, you get what you look for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A section of $\bigwedge^kTM$ is called a *polyvector field* (or multivector field) of degree $k$. Just as you can take the wedge product of differential forms, you can take the wedge product of polyvector fields. Furthermore, there is also the [Schouten-Nijenhuis bracket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schouten%E2%80%93Nijenhuis_bracket) which extends the Lie bracket of vector fields.